# Whats is Openlayers editor?

Tags: openlayers-2

Staff has anyone ever used OpenLayers Editor? 
Openlayers researching on the internet I found this link: https://github.com/geops/ole
It is an editor based on OpenLayers open source? 
How do I set it on my machine to test with PostGIS and GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should publish your PostGIS layer as WFS service using GeoServer. How use OpenLayers.Editor for eding WFS layer see [example](https://github.com/geops/ole/blob/master/examples/wfs.html). All you need is setup `editLayer` property of OpenLayers.Editor.